# NP-Complete algorithm defined on a fixed size array

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

Given an array, say A, with a finite definite length like N (e.g. 1000) can we define a problem to be NP-Complete without any intentional injection of NP-Completeness by something else :

for example questions like this are not acceptable:

"Solve this, NP-Complete, problem using A as an auxiliary array."

---

Please note that N is a predefined constant.

Comment: Do the entries of the array also come from a bounded domain? If so, then the set of inputs is finite, and no problem will be NP complete for them. In fact, every problem is regular in this setting.

Comment: @Shaull It's appreciated if you consider both cases.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is completely unclear. What is the relationship between the array and the possibly-NP-complete problem? Is it the input? The working memory? Something else? What does "intentional injection of NP-Completeness by something else" mean? What does it mean to solve a problem using an auxiliary array?

Answer (score 2):

If the entries of the array are from a finite domain $D$, then every problem (i.e. language) you consider, is restricted to a finite set of inputs, and is thus finite, and in particular, regular.
So for this case, no. Nothing will be NP-complete (unless $P=NP$)

If the entries are unrestricted, for example if every cell can contain a number in $\mathbb{N}$, then looking at an array of length 1000 provides no restrictions. For example, you could consider the problem "Does the contents of the first cell, in binray, represents an encoding of a satisfiable CNF formula"?

This is just a rephrasing of the SAT problem, which is NP-complete.

Comment: You know I agree with you intuitively however I have a little problem with the term "finite". Would you please give an official reference about how a domain is defined finite at all and another one about "So for this case, no. Nothing will be NP-complete. Not even if P=NP."?

Comment: Not sure what kind of "reference" you are looking for. Finite languages are regular, this is a textbook exercise. As for what a finite domain means - it means that the elements are w.l.o.g $\{1,...,d\}$. Then, there is a maximal length of input that can be accepted by the algorithm, which means that the defined language is finite. Finite languages cannot be NP-complete, as it would imply NP=REG, which we know to be false.

Comment: I get this from your comments: Our alphabet given my assumptions is something like elements of the array, and as this alphabet is finite the domain is finite and having a finite domain we cannot define a language that is NP-C, is it right?

Comment: Yes, you could think of $D$ as the alphabet, and then you're essentially looking at a Turing machine with a bounded tape, and a finite alphabet.

Comment: @FrankW - Wow! of course. I don't know what I was thinking.